# How can I run multiple docker nodes on my laptop to simulate a cluster?

Tags: docker, vagrant, cluster-computing

My goal is to simulate a cluster environment where I can test my applications and tools.

I need to have minimum of 3 **Docker nodes** (not container) running, and have access to them over ssh.

I have tried the following:

1 - Installing multiple **VMs Machines** from [Ubuntu MinimalCD](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/MinimalCD)

Result: ended up with huge files to maintain, repeating the process is really harmful, and unpleasant.

2- Downloading **Vagrant box** that has docker inside (there are some [here](http://www.vagrantbox.es/)).

Result: I can't access them over ssh, and can't really fire up more than one box (Ok, I can but it is still not optimal).

3- Tried to run "**Kitematic**" multiple times, but had no success with it.

What do you do to test your clustering tools for docker?
My only "easy" solution is to run multiple instances from some provider and pay per hour usage, but that is really not that easy when I am offline, and when I just don't want to pay.

I don't need to run multiple "**containers**", but multiple "**hosts**", which I can then join together into a single Cluster to simulate distributed Data Center.

Comment: Checkout docker-machine. It has a virtualbox driver that will run docker hosts locally on your machine. What makes it more attractive, compared to vagrant is that it'll configure docker for remote operation and also enable the setup of docker-swarm

Comment: @MarkO'Connor Thanks for the answer. Any idea how to launch multiple "Ubuntu" hosts from some image other than boot2docker.iso that is being downloaded upon creating new machines. I mean in general: any idea how to create docker machines and select the host os?

Answer (score 2):

You could use [docker-machine](https://docs.docker.com/machine/) to create a few VMs locally. You can connect to all of them by changing the environment variables.

You might also be interested in something like https://github.com/dnephin/compose-swarm-sandbox/. It creates multiple docker hosts inside containers using https://github.com/dnephin/docker-swarm-slave.

If you are using something other than swarm, you would just remove that service from `/srv/`.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, dind is really an amazing thing, but I hesitate using it because I lack the ability to imagine how they would perform on the real vms/nodes. However docker-machine appears to solve the problem as well as running multiple hosts using vagrant.

Comment: Apparently I must read more docs on the docker website. I didn't think there would be something as useful as that.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend you to use docker-machine for this purpose as they are very light weight and very easy to install, run and manage.
Try creating 3-4 docker machine, pull the swarm image on them and make a cluster and use docker compose to manage the cluster in one go.

Answer (score 1):

Option 2 should be a valid option but what you looked at was to use a VM box using the docker provisionner. I would recommend looking at [vagrant docker provider](https://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/docker/basics.html) you do not need a vagrant box in this scenario but docker images. The Vagrant file though is still there and you can easily setup your multiple machines from the single Vagrant file

here is a [nice blog](http://blog.zenika.com/index.php?post/2014/10/07/Setting-up-a-development-environment-using-Docker-and-Vagrant) but I am sure there are plenty of other good articles that explains in detail

Comment: Thank you for the answer, however I am looking for run multiple instances of this docker provider and THEN after they are up and running, I want to interact with them.

According to the vagrant page, **"Vagrant will spin up a single instance of a host VM and run multiple containers on this one VM."**.

What I am looking for is running multiple machines (hosts).

Answer (score 1):

I recommend [Running CoreOS on Vagrant](https://coreos.com/os/docs/latest/booting-on-vagrant.html), it has been designed for your request with cluster enable and 3 instances will be started by default.

With `etcd` and `fleetd`, you should be fine to get cluster work properly.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, this helped me. however I am still trying to setup os-independent nodes with dockers. I have some limitations on my cloud-choices (I can only launch Ubuntu machines), that's why I am looking for some local solution to launch ubuntu-machines locally, and repeat that process with the minimum amount of required effort/time.